Two guys and two girls living together
One very attractive blonde girl, one brunette girl with extremely short hair, and two guys live in house together. I want to say it's set in the countryside (not sure what country) and I think it's probably summer time. While they are living together they take turns planning daily activities. For example one of the guys plans an "art" night where the brunette girl poses nude and the other three paint pictures of her. 
At different times throughout the movie both girls hook up with both guys. At one point I think the girls may even have a scene where they kiss in a bed. I don't remember any of the actors but I do remember one scene where the guys are sharing a room and one guy asks the other if he's asleep (I know that's a random detail) but that's all I can remember.
May have been a French film but I honestly can't remember. I would say drama/romance coming of age genre. Definitely filmed in the last 15 years, probably 10 years and very likely within the last 5 years.

Hi. Do you remember the country\language? The year\decade? The genre?

May have been a French film but I honestly can't remember. I would say drama/romance coming of age genre. Definitely filmed in the last 15 years, probably 10 years and very likely within the last 5 years.

Thanks, added. A 2010 French film called Four Lovers seems to have a very similar plot, but the brunette has long hair.

I may be off on this, because you mentioned two male lead characters and this is older than the date range you gave, but it sounds somewhat like Summer Lovers.
This film is about a young American couple who have an open affair with a French woman while on vacation in Greece. The French woman (portrayed by Valerie Quennessen) has short brown hair and the woman from the couple (portrayed by Daryl Hannah) has long blonde hair.
Regarding the "kiss in bed", it sounds like this scene:

In a very tense scene one evening, Cathy encourages Michael to kiss
  Lina. He gives Lina a light peck, but Cathy says it isn't convincing.
  He gradually turns up the heat while watching Cathy intently for her
  reaction. He then kisses Cathy, checking to see how this makes Lina
  feel. The three end up spending the night together. Lina moves in with
  them, and they continue enjoying the island paradise as a threesome.

(Quoted from Wikipedia plot summary).

Nice guess, but no. Definitely 2 guys and 2 girls in the house. Also it is more recent.
